How to set up a service account programmatically in Grafana?
I'm using this documentation: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/serviceaccount/#service-account-api to try and work out how I can provision Grafana dashboards programmatically. This is my understanding so far:

Set up a service account
Set up a token for the service account
Use this token when making HTTP calls to Grafana API (to provision custom dashboards along with other things)

However, the first step of setting up service account "programmatically" is not documented or at least I cannot find it. There are instructions on how to do it via Grafana UI here: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/serviceaccount/#service-account-api but not how to do the same thing programatically.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Do you have some code that you're using?

It is documented:
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/serviceaccount/#create-service-account
POST /api/serviceaccounts HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=

{
  "name": "grafana",
  "role": "Viewer",
  "isDisabled": false
}


I have seen that. Could you please confirm how to get the Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4= mentioned in your snippet above programatically? Thanks.

@HelmBurger see doc: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/#basic-auth

I use Azure SSO / OAuth to log into managed grafana. There is no username and password to do the basic auth.

@HelmBurger so you didn't mention this important detail = you can't use that API programmatically.

You are stuck in an infinite loop. You want to programmatically setup an API key, but to do that you need an API key first... Just go to the UI, create your key, and use Terraform import.
